# Saved files in internal storage disappearing after force stop

Tags: android

I'm running into a problem where files stored in internal memory via context.openFileOutput() are disappearing after I force stop the app. I'll create 2 files, force stop the app, and when I open the app again they're gone. I'm verifying the file's existence by using context.fileList(). My understanding is that this storage is persistent, but I'm not seeing that. Is there something I'm missing?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: no code sample = no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question could have been phrased more pointedly. I didn't post code because I was hoping to hear if anyone had similar experiences or knew of any circumstances that would lead to this sort of behavior.

I did some further testing and found that the storage is very persistent; the behavior I was seeing was a compounded blend of inappropriate and inconsistent methods of interacting with the storage, as well as a broken serializer.